What dashlets are my users using?
I want to know which dashlets my back-office users have in use on their civicrm dashboard.
I was looking into SearchKit, to possibly create a table showing which dashlets are used.
But I cannot figure out where those configurations are stored? It seems logical that there exists a configuration table somewhere? In CiviCRM or Drupal?

Yes, there are two sql tables for this, and they are exposed by the Civi api as "Dashboard" and "DashboardContact". The former defines the dashboard item in-general, and the latter is used to place it on a particular user's home screen.
These entities are currently hidden from SearchKit, probably to reduce clutter & confusion. However you could enable them by removing the @searchable none annotation from the 2 files Civi/Api4/Dashboard.php and Civi/Api4/DashboardContact.php. If that works for you and is useful, consider creating a pull-request to CiviCRM with the proposed change.

If I then combine the SearchKit with FormBuilder, do you think it is doable then, to actually edit which dashlets are active for each user as an admin, and not have to sit together with each user and edit their dashboards?

Yes I think so.
